# Delete Old Workbooks with current workbook based on Date & QTY

Tags: excel, vba

**Hi there,**

I have created a tool for my work that autosaves a backup file every time it is closed.
I would now like to add VBA code that deletes those files once:

**A) There is more than 5 Back-Up files in the folder IF**

**B) Files are older than 1 Week**

> 

I roughly know how to Loop through things but being this is conditioned and the workbooks I am trying to save are not active workbooks I am struggling to wrap my head around how / if this is possible? I also like to keep it simple, if at all possible.

*(I know I could just make it corporate procedure to delete old files but we all know humans cannot be trusted hahaha)*

> 

If of any assistance, this is the code for the autosave:

```vb
If Weekday(Now(), vbSunday) = 3 Or Weekday(Now(), vbSunday) = 4 Or _
                                   Weekday(Now(), vbSunday) = 5 Then

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call ThisWorkbook.SaveAs("[source]\[file name]" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_hh.mmAM/PM") & ".xlsm")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

*(sorry, for corporate reasons I censored the source and file name)*

Muchly appreciate your help!

Cheers
dom

Answer (score 0):

First, use `FileSystemObject` to collect the files from the folder.

Next, if count of files is larger than five, retrieve the archive date from each filename:

```vb
Dim FileName    As String
Dim FileStamp   As String
Dim TextTime    As String
Dim FileTime    As Date

FileName = "YourFileNameYYYYMMDD_hh.mmAM/PM.xlsm"
FileStamp = Left(Right(FileName, 24), 19)
TextTime = Format(Replace(FileStamp, "_", ""), "@@@@ @@ @@ @@@@@ @@")
FileTime = CDate(TextTime)
```

Now, loop the collection of files and, for each file, determine if the file is more than seven days old and, if so, (still using `FileSystemObject`) delete the file:

```vb
If DateDiff("w", FileTime, Date) > 0 Then
    ' Delete the file.
    FileCount = FileCount - 1
End If
```

When `FileCount` reaches five, exit (stop) the loop.

If you are not familiar with `FileSystemObject`, do so - many examples and guides can be found for the browsing.